# Overloading command parameters in LaTeX

Tags: macros

Wondering if you can accomplish all of these variations in LaTeX by defining a custom command:

```
\mycmd{tag}{color}{keyval}
\mycmd{tag}{keyval}
\mycmd{keyval}
```

So it could be used like this:

```
\mycmd{foo}{black}{size=1cm}
\mycmd{foo}{color=black,size=1cm}
\mycmd{tag=foo,color=black,size=1cm}
```

Either one would work. How to define the command so this sort of thing would work?

```
\newcommand\mycmd[3][...]
```

Comment: Noticed the packages I mentioned yesterday: xparse can do this, see the `g` specifier

Comment: while technically possible, you should not do this in latex. LaTeX has clear syntactic guidelines that `{}` delimited arguments should be mandatory, if you want optional arguments as here, then they should be `[]` delimited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement more or less any syntax in tex, but latex has clear guidelines that optional arguments should be `[]` delimited. `\newcommand` only defines commands with at most one option, so to have two you would need to define it in two steps but `xparse` allows it to be declared directly as having two options so for example the following (complete) example test document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\mycmd{O{deftag}O{red}m}{\typeout{tag=#1,color=#2,#3}}
\begin{document}


\mycmd[foo][black]{size=1cm}
\mycmd[foo]{color=black,size=1cm}
\mycmd{tag=foo,color=black,size=1cm}

\end{document}
```

which produces

```
tag=foo,color=black,size=1cm
tag=foo,color=red,color=black,size=1cm
tag=deftag,color=red,tag=foo,color=black,size=1cm
```

Comment: Wondering, does this output actually mean it is a key-value object that can be iterated over like in a property list, or is `size=1cm` just a string.

Comment: @LancePollard it means whatever you define `\mycmd` to make it mean. To TeX there are no strings or objects or anything else `lor=red,t`  is just  a list of 9 character tokens.